# Yii application migrating to linux server

Tags: php, yii

Problem in accessing the load modules,when migrated to Linux servers.
It does not show any errors but failed to fetech the results.
Works fine in windows os.
Initial problem was the table names case sensitive in Linux and window non-case sensitive. 
I renamed the table names

```
  RENAME TABLE main TO Main
```

Model

```
class ListModel extends CActiveRecord {
     const STATUS_PENDING = 0;

public static function model($className=__CLASS__) {
    return parent::model($className);
}

public function tableName() {
    return 'list_model';
}

public function rules() {
    return array(

        array('list_id,list_title,list_user,list_status', 'required'),
        array('list_title', 'length', 'max' => 255),

        array('list_id,list_status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
    );
}
public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'list_id' => 'Id',
        'list_title' => 'Title',
        'list_user' => 'User',
                    'list_status' => 'Status',

    );
}

public function search(){
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->compare('list_id',$this->list_id, true);
    $criteria->compare('list_title',$this->list_title, true);
    $criteria->compare('list_user',$this->list_user

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array('defaultOrder'=>'daillisting_complain_id DESC'),
    ));
}
public static function getCountPending(){
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT('list_id') FROM list_model WHERE list_status=".self::STATUS_PENDING;
    return  (int) Yii::app()->db
      ->createCommand($sql)
      ->queryScalar();

}
```

}

//View

```
  $pending =   ListModel::getCountPending();
  //does not returns any result and fails
```

what is the error with the models not fetching the data

Comment: You're going to have to provide more detail than this. What exactly fails how when, when doing what?

Comment: You must be more specific, check your apache error log and put here

Comment: I have enabled error logs it does not show any error. Yii fails to fetch the result via models in linux server.

Comment: The SQL query in `getCountPending` has a typo (`COUNT('list_id)` should not have a `'`). It couldn't possibly work as written. If you don't see any errors in Yii application logs (which is odd), check the global PHP/Apache logs as well. In the future, it would be a good idea to do your development in a virtual machine running Linux, so you can catch these problems right away.

Comment: query works in view and not in model. When I call model methods it fails

Answer (score 0):

While in Windows server they are not Case sensitive

But Whereas in the Linux it is case sensitive.

You Could Check for the Naming convention for controllers,models

Hope this will help you

Comment: But query is executed in the view and fails in the model. I ran the query in the view it fetches the result but fails in the view

Comment: when anything goes wrong in linux but is good in Windows it implies the case sensitivity. please check with that aspect. That could be the only problem